# Best practice по сбору инфы которая вычисляется вразных класах-сервисах в entity в java проекте

Tags: java

Есть java приложение, и нужно собрать статистическую информацию в entity
в разных классах-сервисах по всему проекту и в конце сохранить в базу.
Какой самый лучший споспоб это сделать?

Comment: Что в этом вопросе значит `статическая информация`? Приведите пример такой информации.

Comment: Да любая информация в обэекте которая вычисляется в разных класах-сервисах в одном сервисе например вычисляется значение одного поля, вдругом сервисе мы можем взять инфу и сохрнаить в другое поле объекта и этот объект является ентити и стакими же полями есть таблица в которую нужно этот обэект сохранить. Интересует именно подход, но самый лучший подход как это сделать.